# WordPress: Add category to custom post type permalink

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like the following permalink structure for three (3) custom post types I have created, which share a common taxonomy:

```
/%category%/%post_type%/%postname%/
```

I have tried several plugins and tutorials with no luck. I am using WordPress 3.5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow instruction, this will maybe help you.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks